# Simulate a multivariable linear model with fixed $R^2$

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, simulation

I am wondering how I can simulate a dataset so that when you run a linear model on it (`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3`, for example), it will have a fixed $R^2$ (variance explained).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the regression parameters ($\beta s$) associated with x1, x2, and x3. If the correlations between the variables are equal to zero, then:

$R^2 = \beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2 + \beta_3^2$

If the predictors are all uncorrelated, then the $\beta s$ are equal to the correlations.

If all you care about is $R^2$ then you've finished - just plug in some values.

Let's say we want $R^2$ to be 0.75. We want three predictors, so we need each of the predictors to correlate with the outcome $r = \sqrt(0.75/3) = 0.5$.

I can generate data which match that correlation matrix using the mvrnorm() function in the MASS package.

Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)

s <- matrix(
  c(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  ncol = 4) 

d <- MASS::mvrnorm(
  n = 100, 
  mu = rep(0, 4), 
  Sigma = s, 
  tol = 1e-6, 
  empirical = TRUE
) %>% as.data.frame()

names(d)[4] <- "y"
cor(d)
lm(y ~ ., data = d) %>%
  summary()
```

And that gives me:

```
Residual standard error: 0.5078 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.75, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7422 
F-statistic:    96 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If you care about the size of the regression parameters, or the correlations between the Xs then I think you're going to need to do some matrix algebra to work things out.

Comment: $\beta^2$ or $\rho^2?$

Comment: If the Xs are uncorrelated and $\beta s$ are standardized, these are the same value.